# Platform.getBundle().getEntry() - how to get complete file URI

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to generate the fullURI of a file(a .javajet template) to read it a generate code out of it.
When I get the Platform.getBundle(pluginId()).getEntry("/") it gives me the following string :

bundleentry://1074.fwk5184781/templates/FlowMain.javajet
which is obviously wrong and hence the template file is not found.
The code is as follows :

> private String getUri(String pluginId, String relativeUri)
>    {
>      String base = Platform.getBundle(pluginId).getEntry("/").toString();
>      String result = base + relativeUri;
>      return result;
>    }

Any idea on how to get the complete URI of this file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the workspace location you can use `Platform.getLocation()`. [Doc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform.html)

If you have a handle on your project you can also use `IProject.getLocation()` to get the location of the project.

Or you can just call `IFile..getFullPath()`.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like this - http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET2/jet_tutorial2.html

Comment: Doest this work for you: Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId); Path path = new Path("your/file.javajet"); URL fileURL = Platform.find(bundle, path);

Comment: What about this: Path path = new Path(Platform.resolve(Platform.find(plugin.getBundle(), new Path(filePath))).getFile()).toFile().toString();  This is quite a hack and there is probably a better way but it seems to work.